# Is it possible to spend from multiple addresses and broadcast just one tx?

Tags: hd-wallets

In bitcoin I can combine UTXO from multiple addresses into a single transaction. In Ethereum it seems that if I want to spend from multiple addresses I need to do N transactions. This makes HD wallets a bit expensive and impractical. Is there any tricks I am missing here?